# Good thermocouples for cooling and/or power generating

Tags: thermoelectricity

I can't figure out if a good thermocouple for thermoelectrical cooling is a good thermocouple for generating power with the Seebeck Effect.

Comment: From a physics perspective, the two are intimately related. The problem usually comes on the engineering side and how one designs a system optimized for one or the other.